# running around 220 insert into mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I have about 20 files which have mysql queries to be run,

Example of file1.php,file2.php,file3.php

```
<?php
$s = array();
foreach($j as $y) {
//codes
$s[] = "($link, $img)";
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO xyz VALUES ".implode(',',$s));
?>
```

file1.php,file2.php,file3.php are more about same and requires insert into queries to be run. //insert into varies on each file and dynamic based on input

I have run.php which

```
<?php
require 'file1.php';
require 'file2.php';
require 'file3.php';
?>
```

so the execution of file1, file2 and file3 depends on run.php

is this safe way to do it? or should i move the mysql insert into at run.php (run all queries together) instead of leaving it in individual files (file1,file2,file3).

What would be the best way to send data from file1.php to run.php? method, echo?

Comment: Why are you doing this with PHP at all? Why not just have mysql execute the files directly?

Comment: file1,2,3 contains php execution

Comment: as for me the best way is:
1. to use classes (framework or own).
2. as minimum use 1 object to run query. all request run through this object
3. sending data... what kind? sql? think better tu mare functions and return value. and than echo in run.php. or as i said upper use classes

Comment: mysql_unbuffered_query() is faster than mysql_query().

Comment: @subdigger, should i wrap the each file in function and then call it in run.php and run the 80-90 insert into sql queries using one query via php?

Comment: @newinhere need to see code. is it the identical files but with different insert values or it a very very different inserts? can you post code?

Comment: its moreover identical insert but with different data

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in doing this. All maters that you initiate the transaction before starting all the queries and commit in the end OR rollback in case of exception.

Comment: yah... problems starts when project becomes huge or when you pick it(project) up after 1 or 3 year and try to understand what is going on =)